# Privacy policy for publishing app on iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I have an app that I wish to sell via iTunes Store. I do not have a website for the app. How can I add privacy policy URL on iTunes Connect?

Can I add a PDF file URL for privacy policy which is hosted on a 3rd party website?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can host the privacy policy on a 3rd party website. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37122962/6995250) StackOverflow answer addresses your query:

> there is no way you can just copy-paste the text, you need to link to a privacy policy on a website for iTunes connect.
>
> I work on a tool called iubenda that fixes this exact problem for app developers and returns a privacy policy url right after the creation of the privacy policy. You might find it useful: [iubenda.com](http://www.iubenda.com/mobile)
>
> Also, [I've written more](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-ios-apps/) about the exact process of the addition of privacy policies on iOS and the App Store, this could help you out as well. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide any URL you like for your privacy policy. Apple can review the link and policy during the review of your application. If it is a problem, they will contact you.

## Format is Not Specified

The technical form and format of the privacy policy is not specified in the guidelines; only a link is required:

> [5.1.1 Data Collection and Storage](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy)
>
> (i) Privacy Policies: **All apps must include a link to their privacy policy in the App Store Connect metadata field and within the app in an easily accessible manner.** The privacy policy must clearly and explicitly:
>   Identify what data, if any, the app/service collects, how it collects that data, and all uses of that data.

I recommend trying and seeing what Apple say or do. If they reject your PDF file URL, then you will know what to fix.